# Screen flickering issues after sleep mode on my laptop(Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, amd-processor

I recently dual-booted Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC and I started facing screen flickering issues. I didn't face any issues when I shifted back to windows so it's def an Ubuntu issue. The screen flickers at the bottom left corner of my PC when I set the refresh rate at 144hz.

I tried changing the refresh rate to 60hz and things got worse, the entire screen started flickering.

**Also, this only happens if I go to sleep mode and turn it back on.**

Can somebody help me with this? I'm not sure what I can do to fix this :(

Thanks in advance.

Device Specs:

- Ryzen 5 4600H
- Nvidia GTX 1650
- 8 GB RAM
- 144hz display

Nvidia drivers are up to date and I couldn't find any AMD drivers.

I checked the system settings for graphics info and it showed: NVIDIA Corporation / AMD® Renoir.

Comment: Same problem here,with a AMD Ryzen 7 4800H. NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 Laptop using Nvidia 470 also tried with 495 , X11 or Wayland, Gnome or XFCE4
The external monitor works just fine

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me, Power mixer: Prefer Maximum Performance.

[image: NVidia X Server Settings]

After trying other drivers and coming back to the 470 (default) , and after shutdown and restart the screen was still flickering on the bottom left corner.
The flickering went away after the power mixer settings change

Comment: That worked for me too, thanks!